# How to get router's external ip address?

Tags: windows, network-programming, ip-address

When I go to my router's configuration page by logging into 192.168.0.1, I see the router's external IP address as: **10.121.69.5**
When I check my public IP address via [ip4.me](https://ip4.me), I get the public ip as: 49.205.114.40
This means that my router doesn't have direct public access to the internet and instead it is behind some NAT setup by my ISP.
**I want to get this ip: 10.121.69.5 programmatically** but I can't seem to find it anywhere on my devices that are connected to the router.

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

The above command gives me my internet public ip: 49.205.114.40
How can I get the intermediate public ip of the router: **10.121.69.5** from a device that is connected to the router.

Comment: You need to get that from the router itself. SSH or whatever you use to get into the router and get it from there. The hosts on your LAN do not know or care about the WAN side of your router, only the router cares about that.

Comment: By the was, the ISP should not be using Private addressing that way. The IETF and IANA have set aside Shared addressing (`100.64.0.0/10`) for ISPs to use for CGN because using Private addressing can conflict with what some customers may be using.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Slightly modifying a diagram from the draft [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-behave-lsn-requirements):

```
Figure 1 summarizes a common network topology in which a CGN
   operates.

                                  .
                                  :
                                  |       Internet
                  ............... | ...................
                                  |       ISP network
                  External pool:  |
                  49.205.114.40/26    |
                              ++------++  External realm
                  ........... |  CGN   |...............
                              ++------++  Internal realm
                       10.121.69.1 |    |
                                |    |
                                |    |    ISP network
                  ............. | .. | ................
                                |    |  Customer premises
                    10.121.69.5 |    | 10.121.69.6
                        ++------++  ++------++
                        |  CPE1  |  |  CPE2  |  etc.
                        ++------++  ++------++
                    192.168.0.1

               (IP addresses are only for example purposes)

                      Figure 1: CGN network topology
```

Your best chance to find out your Internal Realm IP would be to use a traceroute technique. To do this you manually set the TTL on an ICMP or UDP packet to a low level, (probably 0-2), and look for an ICMP message error message (normally type 11). It will hopefully contain the Internal Realm IP.